# require_once() if a product in woocommerce contains a tag

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I try to `require_once()` a file, if the condition of a specific tag is met, on a woocommerce single product page.

I've added following to my `functions.php`

```
if(has_term('xyz', 'product_tag')){
    require_once WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/path/file.php';
}
```

It doesn't load my file, but if I take it out of my condition, it does load.

What can I do to achieve this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_term()` is a template function therefore it does not work if you use it straight in functions.php which is loaded well before knowing if the current object is a product page.
So if you use it in `functions.php` you could do:

```
add_action('template_redirect','my_inclusion_function');
function my_inclusion_function(){
  if(is_product() && has_term('xyz', 'product_tag')){
    require_once( WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/path/file.php');
  }
}
```

`is_product()` checks if you are in a single product and then if the product has tag xyz

If the inclusion has layout implications such as print additional information or so, then this approach is not ideal since the inclusion occurs at the very beginning of the content jsut after the `<body>` tag opening. In this case you can just modify the single-product.php template file (as suggested in the comment by [tiago calado](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/198152/tiago-calado))

Also you can use one of the available hooks in the single-product page check [this useful resource](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/) and use it directly in functions.php. The advantage of this last approach is that you don't have to review the layout pages in case of future theme switch.

Comment: Like a charm! And learned is_product() to know. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

require_once is a function, try this way.

```php
if(has_term('xyz', 'product_tag')){
    require_once( WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/path/file.php');
}
```

also require_once() in functions.php, dont know what to say. give feedback if the code above had work has intended.

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't change anything. How would you include an external file, if the product has a certain tag? I understand that this isnt best practise.

Comment: I customize my single product page creating a folder called woocommerce in the theme directory and then copying the file single-product.php from woocommerce plugin to woocommerce folder on my theme. there you can try to use the require_once() on top of the file single-product.php. probably there will work. if not you can customize the file where you want on the code.

Comment: `require_once` is **not a function**, it's an expression, and it does not need brackets.